# eCharts import does not work. Fails with _DEV__ is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, import, echarts

I installed using NPM, echarts library in this way

```
npm install echarts --save
```

Following the [documentation](http://echarts.baidu.com/tutorial.html#%E8%87%AA%E5%AE%9A%E4%B9%89%E6%9E%84%E5%BB%BA%20ECharts) I wrote in my code

`import * as echarts from 'echarts'`

then I tried a very simple example

```
const $chart = $('#chart')
let myChart = echarts.init($chart)
const option = {
  title: {
    text: 'ECharts entry example'
  },
  tooltip: {},
  legend: {
    data: ['Sales']
  },
  xAxis: {
    data: ['shirt', 'cardign', 'chiffon shirt', 'pants', 'heels', 'socks']
  },
  yAxis: {},
  series: [
    {
      name: 'Sales',
      type: 'bar',
      data: [5, 20, 36, 10, 10, 20]
    }
  ]
}
myChart.setOption(option)
```

but I got this error

```
ReferenceError: __DEV__ is not defined
```

What do you think is the problem? I can't find documentation about this error...

Comment: Seems to be an issue at the moment : see https://github.com/ecomfe/echarts/issues/6111, https://github.com/ecomfe/echarts/issues/6987,

Comment: @DarkUrse there is no solution? I tried to modify the webpack confing without results...

Comment: Honestly I tried to set this `__DEV__` flag in the environment.*.ts to see by adding it to window object `window['\_\_DEV\_\_'] = false; to replace this undefined by a boolean as they are doing at the top of their config.js.  But no dice.

Answer (score 1):

I have import echarts as below and it works

```
import * as echarts from 'echarts/dist/echarts.js';
```

Comment: I tried what you suggest and I got a different error `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): this.dom.getContext is not a function`. Could you please provide your working demo?

Comment: This does not work. at best it removes a warning but doesn't fix the __DEV__ error ( at least in my case )

Answer (score 1):

```
  import * as echarts from 'echarts/lib/echarts'
  import 'echarts/lib/chart/line'
  import 'echarts/lib/chart/bar'
  import 'echarts/lib/component/tooltip'
  import 'echarts/lib/component/title'
  import 'echarts/lib/component/legend'
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me (echarts 4.2.1): `import * as echarts from 'echarts';`

Answer (score 0):

This CDN works for me. Place the script in HTML file in the.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/echarts/4.1.0/echarts-en.common.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The question is specifically dealing with node.js imports, not with including a script in HTML.

Comment: To clarify, if none of the other solutions offered seem to work, this is just a suggestion to start using echarts.

Comment: Hey @HueNgo, You seem to be the only one ever suggested to use echarts from a script src. How do I use the echarts reference inside a static html page?

Comment: @nirshabi Hi, after adding the script src in your HTML page, create a container with id (e.g. `<div id="main"></div>`) where you would like your chart to render. Afterward, initialize the echart object in a script file like so: `var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main'));` this is a good reference for getting started with [echarts](http://man.hubwiz.com/docset/ECharts.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/en/tutorial.html)

Comment: @HueNgo Thanks! I was able to do that. Just had to add the echarts script as async, and added a timeout to the echarts.init function. Kind of a workaround but it works :)